# Проблема взаимосвязи между коллекциями

Tags: c#, классы, коллекции, проектирование

Имеется: 
Класс студент(ФИО, номер группы и тд) - Student

Класс группа(староста(объект класса студент), номер группы и тд) - Group

На основе данных классов, созданы две коллекции:

1. Коллекция студентов - StudentCollection (студенты, с разными номерами групп)
2. Коллекция групп - GroupCollection

Каким образом связать студентов с их группой? (связь на основе номера группы)

Стоит ли в класс Group, в качестве поля, добавить StudentCollection (из общей коллекции, выбирать студентов с номером группы, который совпадает с полем номер группы в классе Group)? Или имеются способы связать данные классы лучше?

Comment: Студент может быть одновременно в нескольких группах? Если нет, добавьте в студента ссылку на группу

Comment: Так у вас же в студенте уже хранится номер группы. Значит ничего не нужно добавлять, если вы ещё и в группу добавьте коллекцию студентов, тогда у вас уже принадлежность студента к группе будет определяться в нескольких местах, что ведёт к ошибкам.

Comment: Лучше оставьте как сейчас, а всех студентов группы можно получить в любой момент например так: `StudentCollection.Where(s => s.GroupNo == 1);`

Comment: @Андрей Я так понимаю у автора номер группы как str хранится. Все-же лучше ссылку на группу.

Comment: @Oleg, с чего такие выводы? Можно и ссылку хранить, но тогда нужно убрать номер, чтобы не было неоднозначностей

Comment: @Oleg,
Да, и в группе и в студенте они хранятся в качестве строки. 

Я правильно понимаю, что наиболее оптимально будет убрать поле номер группу у студента, завести поле Group GroupNum, и в случае необходимости, из группы GroupNum доставать уже строковый номер?

Comment: Это зависит от задачи, которую решает ваш код. Если вам часто нужно обходить группы студентов, нужно в класс Group добавить список студентов (лучше set). Да, двусторонняя связь обычно не приветствуется, но иногда она нужна. Просто придется тщательно следить за одновременным изменением ссылки на группу у студента и изменением набора студентов в группах.